# Is Iterable-like behavior in C++ attainable?

Tags: c++

Java allows classes to reveal `Iterable` types so clients can traverse some instance's collection of data, like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ArrayList<String> strings;
    private ArrayList<Integers> ints;
    public MyClass() { /* generate data ... */ }
    public Iterable<String> allStrings() {return strings;}
    public Iterable<Integer> allInts() {return ints;}
}
```

This has always struck me as "clean" because it maintains encapsulation, allowing me to change the `ArrayList`s to `LinkedList`s if I wanted to and is still convenient to the client in constructs such as `for(String s : myClassInstance.allStrings()) //...`.

In C++, however, if I want to allow the client to use my `for-loop`, in absence of an `Iterable`, I need to return a `const vector<T>&` or whatever, which is obviously not too great.

Defining `template<> begin<my_class> {/*...*/}` and friends is nice, but only if `my_class` has one collection to iterate over. What else can I do?

Comment: C++ has iterators, although they work slightly differently than in Java. In fact the `Iterable<T>` interface is just a layer that allows the Java compiler to use some syntactic sugar to automate the actual iteration.

Comment: @JohnGaughan I never said C++ didn't have iterators - see my solution.

Comment: If `allTs()` returns `const vector<T>&` you can use it to initialize a `const auto&` variable and be insulated from its type.

Comment: @Oktalist True, but that's enforcing a dependency on a client. Further, using any kind of `iterable` introduces a variable dependent on the lifetime of the object itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Tell, don't ask**

If you're frequently exposing the internal representation of your class by allowing a caller to iterate through elements, where's the encapsulation? Collection classes need to expose their elements - that's their purpose.

In C++ it would be preferable and more performant to provide a [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or other [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) mechanism such that each element in the internal collection could be passed in sequence to a Functor. In this way, the containing/visitable class could make some guarantees that the collection won't change while iterating, which may not be possible if you hand out the collection via an iterator.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
struct ElementPrinter
{
  void operator()(const T& elem) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
};

class MyClass 
{
  public:
    // (1) if you only want to print the elements
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& s) const {
       for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = myInts.begin(), 
            end=myInts.end(); it != end; ++it) {
         s << *it << endl;
       }
       return s;
    }

    // (2) if you want a generic way to visit the ints
    template<typename Functor>
    void visitInts(Functor f) {
      std::for_each(myInts.begin(), myInts.end(), f);
    }
};

MyClass m;

// (1)
m.print(std::cout);

// (2)
m.visitInts(ElementPrinter());
```

Comment: Interesting approach! Thanks, this is a good application of the visitor pattern which provides an elegant solution in its different design.

Comment: I'd like to note, however, that you're making some assumptions in your statement "if you're frequently exposing the internal representation of your class by allowing a caller to iterate through elements, where's the encapsulation?"

Both your and Bryan Chen's approaches provide equal encapsulation (assuming forward iterators).

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that using visitor pattern is much safer - no need to worry about the consistency of an old `iterable` instance or the lifespan of the data structure that returned it.

Comment: This code does not provide any notable guarantee that the contents won't change compared to iterator.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica could you please elaborate? In a single-threaded setting, this does seem to eliminate a class of "stale iterator" bugs. I think I accepted it a while ago because it happened to be what I needed at the time, though of course iterators are more flexible (e.g., the very thing that causes stale iterator bugs is that you can defer iteration, which is useful in its own right in some settings).

Answer (score 28):

just make `Iterable` in C++

```
template<class T, class U>
struct Iterable
{
    T _begin;
    U _end;

    Iterable(T begin, U end)
    : _begin(begin), _end(end)
    {}

    T begin()
    {
        return _begin;
    }

    U end()
    {
        return _end;
    }
};

template<class T, class U>
Iterable<T,U> make_iterable(T t, U u)
{
    return Iterable<T,U>(t, u);
}

struct MyClass 
{
    std::vector<int> _ints;
    std::vector<std::string> _strings;

    auto allInts() -> decltype(make_iterable(_ints.begin(), _ints.end()))
    {
        return make_iterable(_ints.begin(), _ints.end());
    }

    auto allStrings() -> decltype(make_iterable(_strings.begin(), _strings.end()))
    {
        return make_iterable(_strings.begin(), _strings.end());
    }
};
```

then use it like

```
for (auto i : foo.allInts())
{
    cout << i << endl;
}

for (auto i : foo.allStrings())
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bf8438c87975694)

Comment: Why both `T` and `U`? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: @C.R. I agree. Bryan Chen, is there a reason the templates differ?

Comment: This is an excellent utility. However, I think @JBRWilkinson's answer is a bit cleaner from a design perspective and requires less code.

Comment: @C.R. Yes they should be same. I just make them different just in case some container have different iterator type for `begin` and `end`

Comment: I noticed in some Microsoft documentation that `begin()` and `end()` can have different types, allowing `end()` to return a sentinel object, as in the Ranges-V3 proposal:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/range-based-for-statement-cpp?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I have (though I hope there are others) is to forgo the nice-looking enhanced for-loop and define several `begin/end` member functions, i.e., `my_class::begin_strings(), my_class::end_strings(), my_class::end_ints(), my_class::begin_ints()`.

Hopefully there are other options, since now clients must use `for(auto it = mci.begin_strings(); it != mci.end_strings(); ++it)`. Not too bad, but still not as pretty as Java (and a lot of code redundancy).